# Rename Multiple files gzips them and delete older than 10 days

Tags: bash, files, scripting, rename, gzip

I'm new to Linux/Unix and slowly learning it step by step. Unfortunately on today’s job interview was surprised by a task to do (which of course I didn’t know). I was asked to prepare a bash script that:

- changes the names of .log. files to (name).(date).log.(remaining part of the original name) and gzips them to a .gz archive.
- deletes (name).(date).log.(remaining part of the original name).gz files older than 10 days.

Never too late for asking and would really appreciate if you could let me know how it should look like.

Comment: Why don't you show us your best attempt and if you succeed, post it as an answer.  Otherwise someone will appreciate the effort you've put in it and complete it for you.

Comment: You might like logrotate

Answer (score 2):

Assuming GNU tools, I'd do something like

```
find . -type f \( -name '*.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9].log.*.gz' \
       \( -mtime -10 -o -delete -o -true \) -o -name '*.log.*' ! -name '*.gz' \
       \( -mtime +9 \( -delete -o -true \) -o -printf '%TF/%p\0' \) \) |
  while IFS=/ read -rd '' date file; do
    basename=${file##*/}
    dirname=${file%/*}
    newfile=$dirname/${basename%.log.*}.$date.log.${basename##*.log.}
    mv "$file" "$newfile" && gzip "$newfile"
  done
```

Comment: Yes its the best answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

workdir="/tmp/myfilestomove"
#cd "$workdir"
[ ! -e "$workdir" ] && exit 

find -type f "$workdir" | grep -v '.gz' | while read file; do
     filedate="$(date -r "$file" +%d%m%Y)"
     basename="${file%.*}"
     extension="${file##*.}"
     echo mv "$file" "${basename}.${filedate}.${extension}" 
     echo gzip "${basename}.${filedate}.${extension}"
done


find -type f -mtime +10 "$workdir" | while read file; do
     echo rm "$file"
done
```

Remove echo only if you tested the script, and do a backup of your files before the first use.

Comment: I advise reworking that for into a find; your script will choke in files with whitespace in the name. Also try to pass the directory to find, and not doing a cd without checking; otherwise you will be working in another directory if the directory does not exist, or is deleted in a reboot.

Comment: I tested it with files with spaces and nothing wrong happens. Maybe this occurs when you forget the double quotes?

Comment: I am trying again now.

Comment: I tested in a folder with space in names and it is working fine are you really using bash or are you using sh?

Comment: I added the check if the directory exists.

Comment: Ok, as you wish. But let me advise you that this script will not work in sh, it is made only for bash. In sh it will broke in the first lines because of the one-line condition and the variable processing.

Comment: excellent. now you can move the workdir to the find, and be done with the cd and the checking.

Comment: As you wish friend. Hope is like you want now. Please make me the right answer.

Comment: If i know that before i wont fixed the script ;-) Just kidding!

Comment: With `read file`, you'd have issues with trailing space/tab, and with newline or backspace characters.

Comment: `-mtime +10` is for files older than 11 days (age in days (rounded up) strictly greater than 10, so 11 or more).

Comment: Note that gzip preserves the modification time, so you may skip compressing older log files as you'd be deleting them afterwards anyway.